# Vue-tables-2 create pdf file from multiple selected table rows using pdfmake library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, pdfmake

I would like to create a pdf of multiple selected rows within vue-tables-2. I have found a pdf library called [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/#/) which looks great. Being new to this, I am struggling to see how I can:

1. bring this into a vue-tables-2 component. Do I import this in the
   component?
2. how would I create a pdf of multiple selected table row data? I have `this.checkedRows` for the tableData content. How do I get this into the pdf?

I see how pdfmake has instructions to build out datatable content, but how can I make this work with vue-tables-2? [pdfmake table content screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAb8j.png)

If anyone knows a better pdf library for vue-tables-2 please let me know. 
Here is my code so far...

```
<v-server-table url="/removals" :data="tableData" :columns="columns" :options="options">

    <input slot="selected" slot-scope="props" type="checkbox" :checked="props.row.selected" v-model="checkedRows" :value="props.row">

    <button slot="afterFilter" type="submit" @click="createPDF">Create PDF</button>

 </v-server-table>
```

My data content is just a very simple prototype right now:

```
data() {
    return {

        tableData: [],

        checkedRows: [],

        columns: [
            'selected',
            'sku',
        ],

        options: {

        }
    }
```

And my method...

```
methods: {

    createPDF() {
        pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('PO.pdf');
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could install `pdfmake` using the following command :

```
 npm install pdfmake --save-dev
```

and import and use it as follow

```
<template>....</template>
<script>
    var pdfMake = require('pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js');
    var pdfFonts = require('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js');
    pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;

    export default{ 

        data() {
            return {
              tableData: [],
              checkedRows: [],
              columns: [
                   'selected',
                   'sku',
               ],

            options: {

                     }
           },
         methods: {

                            createPDF() {
        var docDefinition = {
        content: [
            {
                table: {
                    headerRows: 1,
                    widths: [ '*', 'auto', 100, '*' ],

                    body: []
                }
            }
        ]
        };
        docDefinition.content[0].table.body.push(this.columns);
        for(var i=0;i<this.checkedRows.length;i++){
            docDefinition.content[0].table.body.push(Object.values(this.checkedRows[i]));  
        }
        pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('PO.pdf');
    }



    }
     }
```